# Saving current logged user into DB

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

Im doing a CMS for a little enterprise and i want to save into DB the user that inserted that data is that possibe to be done?

If so please give me a code example or a idea for it Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that.
You could log your User's Name/ID in a Session-Var ($_SESSION) and insert it into your DB when saving the Article.

Comment: can i have a little example or idea pleasE?

Comment: make sure to use 
"start_session()" at the beginning(!) in all of your scripts.
The you can access the $_SESSION['user'] in every Script.

You can then add a line as { $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['user']; } in your login-script.

When saving an entry you can access that Variable again. 
{ mysql_query("UPDATE `article` SET `user`='$_SESSION['uid']."'"; }

(as i just scribbled that down...